# I'm using `MPAndroidChart` in both Android and ios but getting this difference. Can someone please help me out with this?

Tags: android, android-studio, mpandroidchart

Getting this on android
[image]

Getting this on ios
[image]

I'm using `MPAndroidChart` same values for `Android` and `ios` but getting this difference. Need Android screen to be same as ios. I don't know what I'm doing wrong.  It seems like x axis values are being parsed to float where it's losing its precision.

Comment: Hi @kapsid, could you please be able to provide the code snippets for both iOS and Android?

Comment: Hi @Lilya the issue seems to be with the library itself. https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/pull/4121